# Android: Is there a API to know WHEN any app tries to use the Internet

Tags: android, api, wifi

Is there an API to somehow tell me when another application tries to make use of the Internet? ... Or how else may I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an API to somehow tell me when another application tries to make use of the Internet?

Not really. You can use `TrafficStats` to determine bandwidth consumption, but you would have to poll that data.